# Deploying artifacts during test-case - JBoss AS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I have a very specific test case:

1. I have to deploy JAR
2. Do some testing stuff
3. Deploy another JAR
4. Do some more testing

JARs have to be deployed in this specific order (I can't deploy both before invocation of the test method)

Do you know any way to perform such scenario in some JUnit-like environment? 
I know that 1. can be definitely done in Arquillian but I don't know if there's a possibility of performing another deployment inside the test method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Arquillian using the Deployer api from within your TestMethod.

First you have to define your @Deployment to not be managed by Arquillian:

```
@Deployment(name = "X", managed = false)
public static WebArchive manualDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)....
}
```

The next step would be to inject a Deployer:

```
@ArquillianResource
private Deployer deployer;
```

Then from within your @Test method you can call:

```
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToDeploy() {
    deployer.deploy("X")
}
```

If your deployment X is setup for in-container testing (@Deployment.testable=true (default behavior)), you can have the next @Test method be executed inside the deployment you just deployed.

```
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToDeploy() {
    deployer.deploy("X");
}

@Test @OperateOnDeployment("X")
public void shouldNowBeInDeploymentX() {
    // we're now inside X
}
```

By default JUnit TestMethods are executed in random order, but Arquillian JUnit integration provide a @InSequence(n) annotation you can use to force the order of execution.

```
@Test @InSequence(1)
public void shouldBeAbleToDeploy() {
    deployer.deploy("X");
}

@Test @InSequence(2) @OperateOnDeployment("X")
public void shouldNowBeInDeploymentX() {
    // we're now inside X
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test method is just executed - also,  you must be able to deploy from there.  I f you already have setup deplying stuff through set up phase  testing whether it works from test is easy

Comment: I know that the method is just executed. I was wondering if there's a way to configure Arquillian (or any other test-env) to perform deployment within test method. In Arquillian you're able to define several deployments with @Deployment and choose which one to use during test method invocation. If there is no such possibility I'd have to write server-dependent code for deploying stuff, which I'd like to avoid.